# Mixing Inheritance and Tree Structure with Fluent nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, class, inheritance, hierarchy, fluent

Part of a model I'm designing is a hierarchy geographic locations. Since there are multiple layers and share some information I decided to use a class hierarchy like this:

```
public class GeographicNode
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual GeographicNode ParentNode { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<GeographicNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}


public class Region : GeographicNode
{
    public virtual int SomeRegionData { get; set; }
}

public class Country : GeographicNode
{
    public virtual int SomeCountryData { get; set; }
}
```

To map this I'm using a table-per-class-hierarchy method. The Fluent nHibernate mapping looks like this:

```
public class GeographicNodeMap : ClassMap<GeographicNode>
{
    public GeographicNodeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.ParentNode);
        HasMany(x => x.ChildNodes).KeyColumn("Id").Cascade.All();

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type");
    }
}

public class RegionMap : SubclassMap<Region>
{
    public RegionMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.SomeRegionData)
    }
}

public class CountryMap : SubclassMap<Region>
{
    public CountryMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.SomeCountryData)
    }
}
```

**Here is my question:**

When I get a node and try to access ParentNode (or the children), its type is actually GeographicNode, and not the appropriate subclass. So for example if I get Region node and its parent is supposed to be a Country node, I'm unable to cast ParentNode to Country class.

Is there a way to force nHibernate to instantiate the ParentNode and Child objects with their appropriate subclass? This information is stored in the Type column, so it'd seem reasonable for nHibernate to instantiate the correct subclass.

Also are there any major concerns with using inheritance here? Using a class hierarchy reduces the amount of code (at least in the model), but I'm worried that having these implicit rather than explicit relationships (e.g. the parent of a region is always a country) can get me into trouble later...

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone who cares: Inheritance seems to be correctly handled in ActiveRecord, i.e. the Parent/Child nodes are instantiated with the correct subclass and can therefore be casted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about this in my blog here:
http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/04/nhibernate-get-vs-load-and-sub-types.html

It includes a special Cast function that correctly casts NHibernate proxies.

However, the best solution is not to cast, but to build correctly polymorphic code :)

Answer (score 0):

since you mapped it as normal reference nhibernate can not know the type withoput loading the parent, so when lazyloading the parent it does not know its type and creates a proxy of th base class. Two Options to remedy that:

- disable Lazyloading of the reference: `References(x => x.ParentNode).Not.LazyLoad();`
- store the parent type in the record of the child: `ReferenceAny<(x => x.ParentNode).TypeColumn("parenttype")...` then NH will create the correct proxy

i would favor option 1 since it is easy and normally does not mean much to performance